# How to futher tune hyper-parameters with the following trend lines of traning loss and validation loss?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data, hyperparameters

I am training a variational encoder (VAE) with **MSE** loss for 100 epochs, and I got the following training and validation loss. My questions are:

1. Should I keep training given that the improvement of the loss is very minor?
2. Is the learning rate appropriate? I am using learning rate decay in this example, and I tried different init values for learning rate but got similar results.
3. I am planning to select the epoch with **the minimum of the sum of the train and vali loss** for the testing. Is it correct?
4. What other parameters could I tune to make it better? Any other suggestions?
   Thanks.
   [image: traning and validation loss]

Comment: It looks good, both training and validation loss are nearly identical with a low loss. Low loss meaning that the models predictions confidence is very high(the inverse of the loss).  Getting further improvements from this point will take a lot of time tweaking all the hyperparameters.

Comment: @yudhiesh Thanks for the comment. Its very helpful. And, assume I use this one as my final version, is it reasonable to pick up the epoch with min (train loss + vali loss)? or I just use the last epoch?

Comment: You could retrain and save the model at each epoch using ```keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint``` then pick the best one(min val loss and train loss) from there.